# Creating new nodes in xml

Tags: c#, xml

can someone give me a pointer as to whats wrong with this code.
The idea is it looks at the xml file if it finds a match it updates the existing node with the new data, if it doesn't find a match it creates a new node/s with the required data.
But instead of only updating the nodes it creates a duplicate, if i remove the code that creates the new node/s it updates as it should. is this a problem with the loop.?

```
 ListBoxItem mySelectedItem = listBox5.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
        string image = mySelectedItem.Content.ToString();
        XmlDocument xXMLTVDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xXMLTVDoc.Load(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + (@"\Media Center Themer") + @"\MCTDefault.xml");
        XmlNodeList xNodes = xXMLTVDoc.SelectNodes(@"/MediaCenterThemer/Resources/Rcdata/Resource");
        XmlNode xNod = xXMLTVDoc.SelectSingleNode(@"/MediaCenterThemer/Resources/Rcdata/Resource");
        string text1 = "";

        if (listBox5.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Please select image.", "No Image Selected", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
        else if (this.listBox5.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select your Image";
            OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "PNG|*.png|All files|*.*";
            OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);

            System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                text1 = OpenFileDialog1.FileName;
                try
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode xNode in xNodes)
                    {
                        if (image.Equals("COMMON.BACKGROUND.PNG"))
                        {
                            if (xNode.Attributes[0].Value == "COMMON.BACKGROUND.PNG")
                            {
                                xNode.FirstChild.Attributes[0].Value = text1;
                                xXMLTVDoc.Save(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + (@"\Media Center Themer") + @"\MCTDefault.xml");
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (xNode.Attributes[0].Value != mySelectedItem.Content.ToString())
                            {
                                XmlElement node = xXMLTVDoc.CreateElement("Resource");
                                node.SetAttribute("Id", mySelectedItem.Content.ToString());
                                XmlNode parent1 = xNod.ParentNode;
                                XmlElement nodeTitle = xXMLTVDoc.CreateElement("Replace");
                                nodeTitle.SetAttribute("File", text1);
                                node.AppendChild(nodeTitle);
                                parent1.AppendChild(node);
                                xXMLTVDoc.Save(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + (@"\Media Center Themer") + @"\MCTDefault.xml");
                            }
                        }

                        else if (image.Equals("COMMON.ANIMATED.BACKGROUND.PNG"))
                        {
                            if (xNode.Attributes[0].Value == "COMMON.ANIMATED.BACKGROUND.PNG")
                            {
                                xNode.FirstChild.Attributes[0].Value = text1;
                                xXMLTVDoc.Save(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + (@"\Media Center Themer") + @"\MCTDefault.xml");
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (xNode.Attributes[0].Value != mySelectedItem.Content.ToString())
                            {
                                XmlElement node = xXMLTVDoc.CreateElement("Resource");
                                node.SetAttribute("Id", mySelectedItem.Content.ToString());
                                XmlNode parent1 = xNod.ParentNode;
                                XmlElement nodeTitle = xXMLTVDoc.CreateElement("Replace");
                                nodeTitle.SetAttribute("File", text1);
                                node.AppendChild(nodeTitle);
                                parent1.AppendChild(node);
                                xXMLTVDoc.Save(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + (@"\Media Center Themer") + @"\MCTDefault.xml");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Could Not assign Image");
                }
```

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Change the main colors of Media Center to shades of green -->
<MediaCenterThemer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="MCTSchema.xsd">
<TextFormat>
<!-- Color: OffWhite -->
<Text Color="rgb(242,242,242)">
  <Replace Color="rgb(130,240,130)" />
</Text>
<!-- Color: LightBlue -->
<Text Color="rgb(151,217,255)">
  <Replace Color="rgb(80,200,80)" />
</Text>
<!-- Color: MediumBlue -->
<Text Color="rgb(2,166,212)">
  <Replace Color="rgb(10,160,10)" />
</Text>
</TextFormat>
<Legacy>
<!-- Legacy strings (settings). Color: OffWhite -->
<String Color="rgb(242,242,242)">
  <Replace Color="rgb(115,200,110)" />
</String>
<!-- Legacy strings (settings). Color: LightBlue -->
<String Color="rgb(151,217,255)">
  <Replace Color="rgb(70,150,60)" />
</String>
</Legacy>
<Resources>
<Rcdata>
<!-- Picture Resources. Modification of the default background -->
<Resource Id="COMMON.BACKGROUND.PNG">
<Replace File="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\CITV.png" />
</Resource>
<Resource Id="COMMON.ANIMATED.BACKGROUND.PNG">
<Replace File="Theme\bkg-demo.jpg"/>
</Resource>
</Rcdata>
</Resources>
</MediaCenterThemer>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hmm.. I'm having a trouble reproducing your issue. Although I would suggest that you take a look what happens when you try to create new xml node. One thing that pops to my mind is that after you create a new node and save xml file what happens is that you get an extra node in the xNodes list which results in one extra iteration in the foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks, i can see that this line: else if (xNode.Attributes[0].Value != mySelectedItem.Content.ToString()) 
 will always return true as it finds the other node/s and then writes the duplicate node/s, regardless as to whether the same node/s exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
     bool doesNodeExist = false;
     foreach (XmlNode xNode in xNodes)
                    {
                        if (image.Equals("COMMON.BACKGROUND.PNG"))
                        {
                            if (xNode.Attributes[0].Value == "COMMON.BACKGROUND.PNG")
                            {
doesNodeExist = true;
                                xNode.FirstChild.Attributes[0].Value = text1;
                                xXMLTVDoc.Save(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + (@"\Media Center Themer") + @"\MCTDefault.xml");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                   }
       if(!doesNodeExist)
      {
          //Create Logic here...
      }
```